# CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix Error

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, iad

I created Universal App (single view) in Xcode. Because I want to have `iAd` banner on every view I added this code to `AppDelegate` file:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    if var root = self.window?.rootViewController
    {
        let contentFrame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
         var _banner = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.Banner)

        _banner.frame=CGRectMake(0, contentFrame.height - _banner.frame.height, _banner.frame.width, _banner.frame.height)
        _banner.delegate = self
        root.view.addSubview(_banner)
    }

    return true
}
```

On real iPhone (iOS 8) Everything works fine (banner appears on every view) but I'm getting this error:

```
<Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.
```

If i try to run this app on Simulator (iOS 8) the behavior is the same. Everything works fine, i get the same error but moreover i get: *ADBannerView:

```
 Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:):
 Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from 
this banner" UserInfo=0x7b83bf30 {ADInternalErrorCode=7, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner}*
```

But I have delegate and I implemented `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`. On real iPhone it works...

My question is how could I solve these two particular errors?

Answer (score 11):

The most likely cause is that one of the rects here is zero. You can't invert a zero matrix (which is a technical detail, and you really shouldn't have to care about; I'm just trying to say why that's the error you get).

`application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` is called very early, and the frames probably aren't set yet. You probably want to be doing this work in the `viewDidLoad` (possibly fixing up the frames in `viewWillAppear` if necessary) of your root view controller (you probably will need to create a subclass for that if you don't already have one).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm getting these two errors and doesn't matter where is my code placed (I tried ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear). And I tried printed all coord and there is no one with zero value. So I will trust you that I don't have to care about it:)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your viewController class.. replace adBanner with whatever your banner property name is

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [adBanner removeFromSuperview];
    adBanner.delegate = nil;
    adBanner = nil;
}
```